# What is the benefit of order by newid() in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the benefit of `ORDER BY NEWID()` in Sql server?

Comment: return the result in random sequence

Comment: and it's not always the [most efficient way to do it](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/get-random-row-large-table/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although no real question has been asked, NEWID() can be used to order a dataset in a "random" way, but it's not so efficient over a very large amount of records:

```
/*Smaller Datasets*/
Select top 100 *
from dbo.SomeTable 
Order by NEWID() DESC

/*For very large datasets, this seems to be more effiecient*/
Select top 100 *
from dbo.SomeTable
where
(ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
```